# How can I count cumulative variables in pandas, but split the results into different columns?

Tags: python, pandas

For example, my dataset has a column that specifies a user's sex, I want to create two separate columns that each cumulatively count the occurrence of each sex.

```
User - Sex 
1      0
2      1
3      1
4      0
```

I want to turn the above into the table below where males are 0 and females are 1.

```
User - Sex  - Male Count - Female Count
1      0         0              0
2      1         1              0
3      1         1              1
4      0         1              2
```

Comment: Shouldn't either the male or female count have one in the first row?

Comment: It's a cumulative count in pandas, so this is what I would expect my output to be using pandas. If you have a way that works similarly but doesn't have the same exact output that works too.

Comment: I agree with @JANO, this looks like a shifted count

Comment: I understand it looks funny, but this is what the current method I'm using outputs (cumcount() in pandas). The problem with this is that it is cumulatively counting both genders in the same column, and ideally, I'd need a way to split them up.

Comment: Check [`my answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71127805/16343464). If you don't want a shifted count, just remove the `shift`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you rather have a **shifted** cumulated count (i.e. count for the previous rows):

```
s = df['Sex'].eq(0)

df['Male count'] = s.cumsum().shift(fill_value=0)
df['Female count'] = (~s).cumsum().shift(fill_value=0)
```

output:

```
   User  Sex  Male count  Female count
0     1    0           0             0
1     2    1           1             0
2     3    1           1             1
3     4    0           1             2
```